# cross object trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to SFDC and I am trying to write a trigger so that when ever a new contact is associated with a campaign as a campaign member, its lead status should change to "New". 
Can any one suggest me how should I do it.

Comment: Start [with a tutorial](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the **Force.com Workbooks**:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook

I highly suggest going through the `Force.com Workbook` and the `Apex Workbook` (and really, the `Visualforce Workbook` too).  The `Force.com Workbook` gives a broad overview of Salesforce -- and you'll find sections on triggers there.  And the `Apex Workbook` is slightly more advanced though specific to only the *Apex Coding* side of Salesforce (which is a **huge** part of Salesforce).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will surely go through those workbooks